# Ember issue passing data to template using this.render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I want to render a template using render() and want to pass some data(model)

I get the data in template if I pass the parameter as model
model: this.controllerFor(this.routeName).someModel

```
this.render('my-template', {
  into: 'application',
  outlet: 'myOutlet',
  model: this.controllerFor(this.routeName).someModel
});
```

But the below does not work. Is there some restriction on naming for the passed model ?

```
this.render('my-template', {
  into: 'application',
  outlet: 'flyout',
  myModel: this.controllerFor(this.routeName).someModel
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The property you are passing isn't the name for your `model`, it is your `model`.

Whatever you pass as the `model` property will be set as the `model` property on the corresponding controller.

Relevant check that ember does [under the hood of render()](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.7.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L2153) is the following:

```
if (options && options.model) {
  controller.set('model', options.model);
}
```

where options is what you pass as the second argument to `render()`.

One thing worth noting is that this just sets `controller.model` to `controller.someModel`, which is redundant since you already have access to this data.

Answer (score 0):

The `render` method has two parameters: `name` and `options`.

The `options` properties are:

- into
- outlet
- controller
- model

There is nothing called `myModel`. [See docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render).